# Uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have little problem about my code I make `controller/admin/moderators_controller.rb`.

I got an error on compilator `uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)` in `moderators_controller.rb`.

In navigator I got this error:

> superclass must be a Class (Module given)
>   [navigator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXzHD.png)

```rb
class Admin::ModeratorsController < ActionController
  def index
  end
end
```

This is my `routes.rb` file:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :moderators, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve accidentally made your controller inherit from `ActionController` (a module) instead of `ActionController::Base` (a class). You need to add `::Base` to the end there.

If this is Rails 5, the common convention now is to have a `ApplicationController` class in your `app/controllers` folder, and have all controllers inherit from that (it’s just a class that inherits from `ActionController::Base`, but gives you a place to put common methods).

**Rails 5**

```
class Admin::ModeratorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**Rails 4 or below**

```
class Admin::ModeratorsController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end
end
```

Comment: class Admin::ModeratorsController < ActionController::Base work in rails 5.1

Comment: @belhadjabdou, of course it works but use `ApplicationController` because you can need sometimes logics in `ApplicationController`

Comment: @belhadjabdou right. That will work. But on Rails 5, using ApplicationController is preferred, as a place to keep common code. If you change it to `ApplicationController` it should also work (an example is in my post). For more info, read https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html